# What port is used to send request by an Express app?

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I have an Express app A, that is configured to listen on 4455 port.

The app also uses axios to send requests to a different server B.

The server B is configured such that it replies to host:port from which it recieved the request.
In this case server A can't recieve response from B, because in the request the,  port of A keeps changing.

Does express server send and receive messages from the same port?

Comment: Does that mean that server B _makes a new connection to host:port_ to send its response?

Comment: @robertklep: yes.

Answer (score 0):

The port on which Express listens for incoming connections has nothing to do with the port used for requests that happen to be made from the same application.

Requests are typically made from a random(-ish) port, and it would require some effort if you want that port to be fixed (always the same). In fact, I'm not even sure if you can make `axios` use a *specific* local port from which it makes requests.

That leaves the following solution: you make a request using `axios`, somehow (I'm not sure how) record from which local port that request is being made, and after the request has finished, create a temporary (Express) server that listens for the response on that same local port. When server B has sent its response (or after a specific timeout), that server is stopped.

To be honest, the way that server B sends back its responses is quite uncommon, *especially* since requests are almost always made from a random port. I also don't understand why server B cannot send back the response over the existing connection.